# Nominate for Pro Tempore Moderators

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

> For more information on elected members as moderators, refer
>   [Moderator Pro Tempore Announcement](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/moderator-pro-tempore-announcement)

---

As we are now in Public Beta, its time to discuss on *Who should the moderators be?* one of the most important point from [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

Before moving on with nomination information/rules I would like the users to read [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Coming to the information over nomination, ***Deep engagement*** in the community's development is required for all temporary moderator candidates.

**All potential candidates must have :**

> - Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).
>
> **Bonus points for:**
>
> - Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
> - Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
> - Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.
>
> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act
>   as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections
>   after the Beta period. Besides the normal abilities of a Moderator,
>   they will:
>
> 1. Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing.
> 2. Organize the process of selecting the site’s attributes (domain names, design issues, the [help center], etc.).
> 3. Rally community support and drive the mission of getting publicity for the site.
>
> Essentially, **they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for
>   anything we can do to help their sites succeed!**

---

Rules for Nominating users to serve as moderators for the public beta

For each user that you would like to nominate,

- Post an answer containing the URLs to both of the user's **main and meta profiles on this site**
- Optionally, link to the user's **Area 51 profile** or a profile from another site, or add a reason why you'd like him/her to moderate during beta
- **Self-Nominations** (i.e. posting your own profiles) are allowed and even encouraged
- Post each user as a **separate answer**, and add multiple answers if you wish to nominate multiple users

Additionally, if someone nominates *you*, please **edit the answer** to indicate your approval (or declination). Optionally, add a paragraph or two about yourself.

If you downvote a particular nomination, you are encouraged to **share why** you did so in the comments, though you are not required to do so. Optionally, you may do the same for upvotes.

<sup>Some parts adapted from [meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/67/1925)</sup>

---

**Note** : Unlike other Beta websites where the users are generic, this one will mostly attract Indian users. As our Private Beta was extended unfortunately because of the lack of Quality Content, I would like the users to vote the candidates wisely.

Comment: How many vacancies for mods? I would like to be one, but... there are two great contenders already here - you and Ankit.

Comment: @AwalGarg no limits for nominations but only **3** vacancies for mod as of now.

Comment: Actually, I am refraining because I think there are 2 good nominations already there... Mods are not extra terrestrial people. They do what we do, just they have more privileges...

Comment: @Shog9 So how will the mods be selected for this website? as buddhism has the post as featured

Comment: I've already started sending out emails to folks I think would make good moderators, @Mr.Alien - I have a short list to go through, but I'll keep an eye on this as well.

Comment: @Shog9 Ohh, didn't knew that, thanks for the info

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for the information.

Comment: "_Note: If there are 10 or less candidates at the end of this phase, we skip directly to Election._" [source](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/) This worries me. the second phase is important and interesting...

Comment: @AwalGarg That is not for Beta websites :) Read shogs comment

Answer (score 11):

## Self Nomination

[Main Profile](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/124/mr-alien) | [Meta Profile](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/124/mr-alien)

Reasons I would like to self nominate :-

- One of the most Active user on Hinduism.SE
- Actively participate in Chat Room
- Actively participate in Meta
- Enthusiast as well as well Informed over particular Hinduism topics

Apart from above points, I am highly active on the main site i.e [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542290/mr-alien) where I have access to moderator tools.

Statistics on Stackoverflow :

- Reputation > 50K
- 2,500 > Revisions
- 1,700 > Reviews
- **2598 Helpful Flags**
- Owner of one of the most active rooms on Stackoverflow - [HTML/CSS/WebDesign](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign)

I am online for hours as am a web developer, also, I don't have any surfing restrictions as I work from home.

Comment: I was thinking to do this myself but currently i got stuck in some work. Anyways +1, i think you will be a good contender.

Comment: You makes me feel proud ... I am also owner of same chatroom :)

Answer (score 10):

I nominate the user **senshin**; here's his [main page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/13/senshin) and [meta page](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/senshin).

One need only examine his volumnious and consistent participation in reviewing and editing activities to see his level of commitment to the site; he's made 131 edits, more than the next six people combined.  His contributions to meta have garnered widespread consensus, and he's the most active meta user.  He would have a higher reputation if it weren't for all his downvotes in service of quality control.  I think I speak for most of us when I say that we would have benefited immensely if senshin had had access to moderation tools and a line to the StackExchange Team from day 1 of the private beta, and I hope he can continue to improve the site as a moderator.

---

## Accept

> Whoops, missed this. I accept the nomination. As Caleb notes, Buddhism
>   has moderators now, and I am not one of them. (I've not been terribly
>   active on the main site for the past few days because of real-life
>   issues keeping me busy, but I should be back in a day or two.)

Comment: Senshin will be fit as a mod for Hinduism but I doubt he will get some time to moderate here as he is already looking forward for Buddhism moderation which is also a fresh public beta ... Lets see what senshin has to say over this

Comment: @senshin before voting, i want to know your opinion on it. I mean do you really want to be a mod here or not.

Comment: **+1** senshin took the time to drop by other religion sites and chat rooms asking about how other sites had dealt with issues. This is exactly the sort of thing you want to see in a moderator and my observation was that he was on the right track in identifying potential issues.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I don't think that's a valid concern any more as Buddhism has [an appointed pro-tempore mod slate](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) now and senshin is not on it. If he's interested here...

Comment: Whoops, missed this. I accept the nomination. As Caleb notes, Buddhism has moderators now, and I am not one of them. (I've not been terribly active on the main site for the past few days because of real-life issues keeping me busy, but I should be back in a day or two.)

Comment: @senshin You should edit my answer and include your acceptance.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I would, but I don't have enough rep for that (1000 rep to make edits on meta, now that we're in public beta).

Comment: @senshin that's what i want to listen for you, +1.

Comment: @senshin you would be good for moderating here.. +1

Answer (score 10):

I would like to nominate **Ankit Sharma**

[Main Profile](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/76/ankit-sharma) | [Meta Profile](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76/ankit-sharma) | [Area 51 Profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/55836/ankit-sharma)

Reasons for which I would like to nominate him :

- One of the most Active user on Hinduism.SE
- Fair amount of reputation
- Decent knowledge on Hinduism
- Actively participates on meta
- Owner of Hinduism room

Apart from that, I see very few users who are members on other StackExchange sites as well, whereas Ankit is very active on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190/) which is also in Beta mode.

As a user for > 2 years, I assume that he is aware of how the StackExchange works, also because he has > 10K reputation on Movies & TV and hence he has access to the Moderator Tools as well.

---

## Accept

> I accept the nomination. On the side not i am open minded Hinduism
>   believer, And as you said, i am pretty much aware to trusted user
>   privileges over Movies & TV. And you have mentioned pretty much all
>   the highlights here. I will just want to say, i will love to have
>   diamond symbol after my name and if i didn't got selected....i will
>   still be around here.

Comment: I accept the nomination. On the side not i am open minded Hinduism believer, And as you said, i am pretty much aware to trusted user privileges over Movies & TV. And you have mentioned pretty much all the highlights here. I will just want to say, i will love to have diamond symbol after my name and if i didn't got selected....i will still  be around here.

Comment: Yes, we need open minded mods to counter strict pedantic mods... :P

Comment: @VineetMenon i am quite late to read this but thanx anyways.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to **nominate myself**

[Main Profile](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/38/jabahar) | [Meta Profile](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38/jabahar)

- The reason I would like to nominate myself is because, this being a site about religion **I think there should be at least one moderator who not only studies the religion, but practices it as well**. I am a Vaishnava and follw the path of devotion and knowledge. Apart from this I am familiar with different paths and aspects of Hinduism. So **I will be able to moderate and help other moderators in scrutinizing questions, answers and other related matters**.
- I have some experience of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013923/jabahar), so I am aware of the moderation policies.  I may not be able to participate in the Q&A section much as a mod, but I'll be able to help others make it a great platform where other users can flourish.
- Because I am not into jobs, I can dedicate my time here in reviewing the content and help in keeping the site clean, error free and authentic.

For these reasons, I submit my nomination.

Comment: I would really like to see you as a mod

Comment: Not to suggest you wouldn't make a decent moderator, but this nomination does suggest some miss-understandings about the SE system you should be aware of. It is not moderators' job to police the content of posts for accuracy. It is their job to keep the site clean, but "error free" is simply not on their shoulders—the scrutiny you would need to provide as a moderator is in regard to site guidelines, not in regard to the way they represent Hinduism. Are you sure your interest is really in what the job entails or would your skill-set and knowledge be better matched to other participation?

Comment: @Caleb Well, in that case I am relieved of some task and it makes my job easier to participate both as a contributor and moderator. However, I nominated myself because I heard that senshin was interested and was going to be mod at Buddism.SE due to his popularity. But now that I know he is free, I think he should accept his nomination. If he does, I would be happy to see him as a moderator in place of me.

Comment: @jabahar While I by no means think you would be a bad moderator, I think your time might be better spent focusing on posting answers - your answers on the site so far have been excellent almost without exception, and that's really what the site needs more of. Moderating this site is bound to be a significant time drain because we're going to inevitably have an unusually large amount of low-quality content (relative to other sites of a similar size), simply because of this site's demographics and subject matter.

Comment: @senshin yes, to be a contributor was my primary interest. But I was also interested in the overall quality of site. Now that you have accepted your nomination, I know you will do a very good job. So if I was going to be a moderator, I swap it with you. Mr.Alien and you were in my mind, Ankit also showed interest to be a mod. But since you were to be a mod at Buddhism I submitted my nomination. But now I replace it with you :)

Comment: What Vaishnava sampradaya?

Comment: @cheenbabes Shri Jagannath tradition of Odisha, I also follow teachings of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and other Vaishnava saints.

Comment: @jabahar What does that mean?  I wasn't aware that the Puri Jagannath temple had a particular philosophical tradition associated with it, other than generally being frequented by Vaishnavas because it's a Krishna temple.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yes, it had...but that's not so widespread just local culture.

Comment: @jabahar Interesting, I never knew that.  So what are the philosophical beliefs associated with the tradition of the Puri Jagannath temple?

Comment: @jabahar upvote on Keshav's comment, I'm interested to hear this as well.