# Moderator Pro Tempore Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators, announcements

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Keshav Srinivasan]
[image: The Destroyer]
[image: Pandya]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Hi @Pandya . Editing this post to include the names of the latest set of moderators is incorrect. We are losing the chronology of moderation. The original post was made in 2014 and was meant to be an announcement of one of the first set of moderators. A separate post has already been made by Pops, Community Manager, to announce the new set of moderators. Editing this post is incorrect. Please restore it to its original state.

Comment: Editing the post is fine, @moonstar2001 - there's a revision history. It's more useful to have a place that reflects the *current* pro tempore mods than to keep this as a fixed historical marker.

Comment: I disagree but will not argue further.

Answer (score 16):

First of all I would like to thank SE team, especially Shog9 for considering me as a user who can moderate Hinduism.SE

I would also like to thank my fellow friends out here for supporting me.

Lets make this site a place where users can get the best information on Hinduism.

Comment: I love to see you one of them. I know you all as trio can work well and anyways we others are also here to help you :). Anyways Congratulations and remember "With Great power comes with great responsibility".

Comment: Congratulations..... :p