# How can I make a particular post of interest, to be shown on the main page of active posts?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, recent-activity, meta

I added an extra answer to a question because I did not want the question to get lost in the sea of comments already existing and I wanted to bump the original question up on the main page.

Mods deleted it. I do not want it to be converted into a comment. I want my request for an update to be prominent on the original question. **How do we achieve this?**

Comment: Can you clarify which Q/A posts you're talking about?

Comment: @Pandya It's [this answer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/737/2995) converted to [a comment](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/708/should-we-change-at-least-one-of-our-current-moderators#comment2581_708).

Comment: Anyway, I think mod is justified in _this_ case. Posting comments as answers to draw attention sets a bad precedent.

Comment: @sv. Yes. that was not looking an answer from any angle. Right

Comment: @moonstar2001 how did you judge that "site moderation is going from bad to worse"?

Comment: @moonstar2001 That is not an answer but a question..So i think u were better off posting it as a separate question..

Comment: And again we have an issue because a mod converted a comment like answer to a comment?

Comment: **Who said meta don't need moderation?** You submitted comment as an answer to bump your request. But in the end it was a comment only. Hence, necessary actions were taken i.e to convert your answer into a comment.

Comment: "how did you judge that "site moderation is going from bad to worse"? "..@Pandya  a site like this does not require too much of moderation..But having said that in situations where intervention is required if a Mod falters repeatedly then like moonstar said it can be assumed that the quality of moderation is going down..The problem is not that quality of moderation is going down the real problem i think is that we have only one Mod here who takes all the decisions..and i think its too much of pressure on him too.....

Comment: As a recent example see [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16615/did-lord-buddha-really-not-believe-in-god-and-the-vedas-if-so-why)..While everyone thought otherwise the moderator thought this as a exact duplicate of some other Q..and it took our votes to re-open it..We definitely need another Mod here..I think either sv or the destroyer will do a good job..

Comment: To be on the safer side, I have changed the title of this post to the actual Qn you were asking. With the current form of Qn, it's not required to delete and is answerable. Also, removed the uncalled "criticism" part. We should also understand that the moderation complaints is only from few countable users only. Present direction of community is decided by only a single person. That's also fine, but according to me, the thinking is narrow and is Not all-inclusive. If that changes, then we should be fine even with 1 active. In any case, let's resort to the systematic way for all our grievances.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Editing your existing answer with minor edits would do the trick. Your second answer was more like a comment. So I don't think mods were unfair about this.

Comment: Clarification: Okay my Q has two parts. One- how does one bump up an answer. I agree that my previous answer was more a comment. Two- Why are mods moderating meta? This Q remains. Thanks @iammilind et al.

Answer (score 5):

1. > **Q.** How can I make a particular post of interest, to be shown on the main page of active posts?

   Just edit your Q/A post and you'll find it raised on top at `active` tab. In other words, you can just edit/improve/revise the post to make the question active.

   Visit [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/260388)

   > You can "bump" your question by **editing** the question to provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself.

---

2. > **Q.** I want my request for an update to be prominent on the original question. How do we achieve this?

   Though you [can't start bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78264/260388) following are work-around for it depending on nature and importance of question:

   - Edit the post to bump it to the top of the active tab.
   - Post it on chat and discuss.
   - Ask moderator to add [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag so-that it will show up on the sidebar of the main site.

   Reference: [How to get attention to a post on a child meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188814/260388)

---

- Now, talking about your answer, [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/737/2995) ***doesn't qualify as an answer.***

  From [What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/260388):

  > For answers, any post that is [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/148099) (should be a **comment, doesn't answer the question**, etc.) should be deleted.

---

- Talking about moderation, users selected by [moderator pro tempore](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/184/277) moderates main as well as meta of beta sites. *Ultimately* StackExchange [community managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) occasionally help, review and moderate beta sites.